# Random number generator code fix (alternative for srand48/drand48)

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, random

Let me start by saying that I know near nothing about C and C++. In fact, as a Mathematics major, I'm totally new to programming. That being said, I need to wrap some older code so am trying to struggle through it. Now, when trying to run a test, I get the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol srand48 referenced in
>   function main PokerEval   C:\Users\M.Faas\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Pokerproject\PokerEvalC\PokerEval\allfive.obj   1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol drand48 referenced in
>   function shuffle_deck PokerEval   C:\Users\M.Faas\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2017\Projects\Pokerproject\PokerEvalC\PokerEval\pokerlib.obj   1
>   Error LNK1120 2 unresolved
>   externals PokerEval   C:\Users\M.Faas\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Pokerproject\PokerEvalC\PokerEval\x64\Debug\PokerEval.exe   1

And the same for drand48.

The code I'm using starts as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "arrays.h"
#include "poker.h"

void srand48();
double drand48();
```

And continues to use srand48 and drand48 in these snippets of code:

```
// Seed the random number generator.
srand48(getpid());
```

And for drand48:

```
//
//  This routine takes a deck and randomly mixes up
//  the order of the cards.
//
void
shuffle_deck(int *deck)
{
    int i, n, temp[52];

    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        temp[i] = deck[i];

    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        do {
            n = (int)(51.9999999 * drand48());
        } while (temp[n] == 0);
        deck[i] = temp[n];
        temp[n] = 0;
    }
}
```

The full code can be found here: http://suffe.cool/poker/code/

But I can't think of a way to fix this issue, even though it seems very minor. That said, speed is absolutely essential, as the code will be run several millions of times. I'm using visualstudio on a x64 machine.

Comment: First of all, c or c++?

Comment: And when adding error output, copy-paste the *actual* output instead of rewriting it. And if you *did* copy-paste it then you probably haven't read it.

Comment: Source is in C. I'm using visual studio though, so that would be visual c++. I don't know how this would affect things.

Comment: @MitchellFaas it **very much** does, now please edit the question and fix the issues mentioned above^

Comment: `srand48` and `drand48` are not part of the C or C++ standard libraries. They are defined in POSIX, so if Visual Studio provides POSIX support you'll have to turn that on.

Comment: You probably need to implement `srand48` and `drand48`.

Comment: The `drand48` and related functions are part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/srand48.html). That's the standard for Unix and Unix-like systems (like macOS and Linux). Windows with Visual Studio does *not* have these functions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I understand that it does, just not how. That's why I added the comment about visual studio.  The error is fixed now.

Comment: Most probably visual studio doesn't even support  these functions (never used them myself so I don't really know). However, try to include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @DimChtz I tried that, but that didn't work. Sorry for not including it in the post.

Comment: simple fix if quality isn't that important: `#define srand48(x) srand((int)(x))` and `#define drand48() ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)`...

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        do {
            n = (int)(51.9999999 * drand48());
        } while (temp[n] == 0);` is very inefficient.  Only 51 calls to `drand48()` should be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These declarations

```
void srand48();
double drand48();
```

are deprecated, you should use full prototypes instead:

```
void srand48(long);
double drand48(void);
```

or better include the header where they are declared.

But your problem is that these functions don't even exist on windows. So just remove these declarations. You can emulate these functions (with maybe a bit lower quality of the random numbers) using the standard `srand()` and `rand()` functions (declared in `stdlib.h`) like this:

```
#define srand48(x) srand((int)(x))
#define drand48() ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)
```

Here's a little PoC example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define srand48(x) srand((int)(x))
#define drand48() ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)

int main(void)
{
    srand48(time(0));

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("%f\n", drand48());
    }
}
```

Comment: [`drand48()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) returns ...  values uniformly distributed over the interval [0.0, 1.0) - never 1.0.  `((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)` returns a values in the [0.0, 1.0].  A better emulation would be `(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0))`.

Comment: `srand(unsigned int seed)` expects an `unsigned`.  Unclear why this answer uses `srand((int)(x))` rather than just `srand(x)` or `srand((unsigned)(x))`.  The `(int)` cast should not be used.